# What is the best way to query mongodb with mongoose with an array of IDs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, async.js

I query one collection (messages) with mongoose. The result is an array of documents. Each document contains an ID for a different collection (users). Now I want to query the users collection for each ID from the messages collection.
The idea is to update each message object with the information from the user collection before returning it to the front end.
I tried using async.each. For some reason the final function is never called even though I am making sure the callback() function is called after each iteration.

```
app.get('/getmsg', function(req, res){

 messages.find({query})
 .exec(function(err, ms){
  if(err) throw err;
  async.each(ms, function(m, callback){
   users.findOne({_id : m.userId})
    .lean()
    .exec(function(err, user){
      if(err) {
       console.log('error' , err);
       callback();
      } else {
      m.userName = user.name;

// everything is working up to here

     callback();
    }
  }), function(err){
      res.send(ms);  // this is never returned!
     }
 });
});
```

});

Is there a better way of achieving this? I assume this must be a common issue.

Thanks!

Comment: [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/). Look it up.

Comment: Also `messages.find({query})` is horribly wrong. This expands to `.find({ "query": query })` where you likely want `.find(query)` unless you actually have a property in your documents called `"query"`. Which you likely do not.

Comment: Simply `users.find({ "_id": { "$in": ms.map( m => m.userId) } })`. No need to loop. For those to lazy to look it up.

Comment: Thanks Neil. I only put 'query' to indicate that I am querying for a result in mongodb. The real query is somewhat complex and what left out since it was not necessary to illustrate the question. I will experiment with $in and especially with the map function to avoid the loop for the 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use res.send. Instead create a function to get notified about it. Something like this.

```
// 1st para in async.each() is the array of items
async.each(items,
// 2nd param is the function that each item is passed to
function(item, callback){
// Call an asynchronous function, often a save() to DB
item.someAsyncCall(function (){
  // Async call is done, alert via callback
  callback();
});
},
// 3rd param is the function to call when everything's done
function(err){
// All tasks are done now
doSomethingOnceAllAreDone();
}
);
```